# How to append html contents into word using outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to append contents of a html document(with formatting) at the end of a word document (which already has some contents in it). I am using vba in outlook. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What isn't working with the code you are using? Is the code failing? Please edit your question and add the relevant code and explain what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Create a range at the end of the document, then call `Range.insertFile`.

Comment: @user2693759 Great! If the post answers your question, please mark it as such.